# PHP: get the number of arguments to script

Tags: php

I cannot find (aka: `don't have time to read all the manuals`) a way to get the number of arguments passed to a php script.
I have a fixed argument, `"id"` and, after that, nothing or a list of dynamic arguments.
I actually handle the case of a `not empty list` but I cannot check if the list (after `"id"`) is empty because the arguments are dynamic so, unknown.

first case, handled:

***php_script.php?id=123&aaa=xxx&bbb=yyy***

second case, not handled:

***php_script.php?id=456***

Is there a way ?

I tried `$argv` and `$argc` but I get an error.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: argv in...
```

Comment: AKA didn't read [**any** of the manual?](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)

Comment: `$_GET` Is your variable which you want! Just do: `print_r($_GET);` And you see how you can use it

Comment: @Oliver to read of *any* I have to know about any, don't you think ? But thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

```
$arg_num = count($_GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just pass the argument with $_GET variable, you can use:

```
$num = count($_GET);
```

Hope this helps